# Visual Studio 2008 Crystal Reports Basic (displaying data)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, grouping

I'm using crystal reports basic with visual studio 2008.  When my data is displayed in a table the details section will show the first item, but if the next item has the same information as the box above it will show empty.  This only happens on some of the rows though.  If I do a sum on the the value in the box it will show the correct amount as if all the rows were being displayed properly.  How can I have it show all the information in each box?

Here is a simple layout of what I'm doing and the problem:

Daniel

Payment Period        Amount Owed      Amount Paid

```
       1            $ 200                   $0

       2                                    $0

       3                                    $0

       4            $ 198                   $0

 Total Amount Owed: $ 798
```

I need it to display all the $200 amounts and not leave it blank.  Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a property of each field called 'suppress if duplicated' on the Common tab.  Make sure it's unchecked.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm not seeing the option for "suppress if duplicated".  I looked into it and it should just be in the action properties menu.  Do you have any thoughts on how to display the tab?

Comment: Right-click on the field in design view, select 'format field...' from the drop-down menu, then select the common tab.

Comment: I don't have that option, went through and tried adding tools but no luck.  I did find an alternative way to accomplish it and posted it.  Thanks for the help Beth.

Answer (score 0):

Beth put me on the right path.  I did find a different way to do it, couldn't get the common tab w/ suppress if duplicated to ever appear.

Go to View and then Properties Windows or (F4) in the Properties Window for the field.  Scroll down to the Other option and set HideDuplicates to none.